# How to use @casl/vue with pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia, casl

I'm currently using @casl/ability with Vue 3 but I can't figure out how to make it work with Pinia.

Here's what my `app.js` looks like:

```js
import { createApp } from "vue"
const app = createApp({})

// pinia
import pinia from "./store"
app.use(pinia)

// casl
import { abilitiesPlugin } from "@casl/vue"
import ability from "./cacl/ability"
app.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability, {
    useGlobalProperties: true
})

// ...

app.mount('#app')
```

And here's what my `ability.js` looks like:

```js
import { defineAbility } from "@casl/ability"
import { useMainStore } from "../store/main"

const ability = defineAbility((can, cannot) => {
    const store = useMainStore()
    if (store.user.role === "admin") {
        can("read", "Post")
    }
    // ...
})

export default ability
```

And I'm getting this error:
[image]

I've checked Pinia's documentation about [Using a store outside of a component](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html) but I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong here? (P.S. Pinia is working as expected for the rest of my project. I'm just not sure how to make it work here.)

Comment: I don't use casl but the error means that defineAbility immediately executes a callback and accesses a store before Pinia was initialized. This can be resolved by extracting code from main.js to maintain a proper execution order. But in this case this probably means that defineAbility is misused. That it's eagerly executed likely means that it's supposed to be used in the place where a role is checked, i.e. a component. Doing this at the top of the app will prevent this

Answer (score 0):

maybe you better define rules in pinia. To use ability there you have to make it available inside the store (similar to vue-router):

main.js:

```
import { abilitiesPlugin } from "@casl/vue";
import { createMongoAbility } from "@casl/ability";

const ability = createMongoAbility();
app.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability);
pinia.use(({ store }) => {
  store.ability = markRaw(ability);
});
```

In store.js you are able to access ability now like this:

```
actions: {
  initCasl() {
    const builder = new AbilityBuilder(this.ability);
    if (this.user.role === "admin") {
      builder.can("read", "Post")
    }
    this.ability.update(builder.rules);
  }
}
```